# Google Maps Api V3 - Editable info windows

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

i wanted to ask if there is any way to make infowindows editable? So far i am using simply way to achieve that. When first time infowindow is created, it contains textarea. That lets me to write whatever i want, and then save it using ajax to database. The problem is, i need more functionality. 
When you go to "My maps" or "My places" in google.maps(dunno english translation) you can add marker there, and then info window pops up and it let you use HTML edit ... i would love to get that in my infowindows, or any other way, any other "editor".... anyone knows how to achieve that?
[Photo to "editor" in my maps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zAmeS.jpg)

Photo is from -> http://maps.google.pl/ -> My Maps (available when logged in) -> Edit/Add map -> put a marker on the map. 
Source code is kinda... complicated ..

Comment: well, its google maps, but i added link, and the code is too complicated to find anything

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google Maps uses the `contentEditable` attribute to make an editable HTML section.  The below code creates an editable `div` with buttons to make the selection bold and italic.  You would use innerHTML to get the resultant HTML.

```
<div id="mydiv" contenteditable="true">Edit Me</div>
<button onclick="document.execCommand('bold',null,false);">B</button>
<button onclick="document.execCommand('italic',null,false);">I</button>
<button onclick="alert(document.getElementById('mydiv').innerHTML)">Show HTML</button>
```

You can learn more on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Content_Editable).

Answer (score 2):

You can set the content of your infowindow to be a DOM node. This means you can create your own interface inside the infowindow.

```
infowindow.setContent(mynode);
```